# How to configure OpenSSH to ask for user name instead of using current local login?

Tags: ssh

When I use ssh command to log in to a remote shell, my local user name is used and only password (or a certificate passphrase) is requested. How do I login as a different remote user without adding this user on my local PC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
ssh username@hostname
```

or

```
ssh -l username hostname
```

Either one works.

Answer (score 6):

I normally use slogin instead of ssh - the difference is minimal (both are parts of OpenSSH). With slogin you use this form:

```
slogin user@host
```

slogin was designed to replace rlogin (thus the name). This should work almost anywhere that OpenSSH is installed (technically, you don't need to install the r* replacements, but they usually are...)

One more thing: you can configure OpenSSH to use a particular user name when you log into a remote host - like so (in `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host fred
  User moxie

Host gabbie
  User mpotts

Host serial
  Hostname vx-port-lx08486-px-l1
  User fred
```

Then use ssh like so:

```
ssh gabbie
```

(will log in as mpotts). The example for `serial` will also allow the shorthand name "serial" instead of the long and hard to remember hostname - with username.

Comment: +1 for the `~/.ssh/config` - this makes life so much easier.

Comment: On OS X at least, `slogin` is a symlink to `ssh`, so the differences are minimal indeed.

Answer (score 4):

`ssh <user>@<host>` or `ssh -l <user> <host>` are two ways to specify the user you want to connect as.